# Is it possible to characterize all quotient rings of $\mathbb{C}[t]$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $I$ be a non-zero non-trivial ideal of $R:=\mathbb{C}[t]$.
It is known that $I=(f)$, for some $f \in R$.

If $I$ is a prime or maximal ideal, then $\frac{R}{I}$ is an integral domain or a field, respectively.

If, for example $I=(t^2)$, then $\frac{R}{I}$ is not an integral domain.

> Is there something interesting to say about $\frac{R}{I}$ in general?

By interesting I mean to find all isomorphism classes, for $I$ not prime.

Any comments and hints are welcome!

Comment: You can use the Chinese remainder theorem to show that every quotient ring is either $\mathbb{C}[t]$ itself (when the ideal is zero) or else isomorphic to a finite product of rings of the form $\mathbb{C}[t]/t^n$. Start by writing down the factorization of $f$.

Comment: Great! I think that your comment is what I was looking for. (You can write your comment as an answer, if you like). Please, is it possible to generalize your idea to $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and $I=(f,g)$, $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$? (I guess no? Perhaps another idea is required).

Comment: Is CRT still applicable to $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and $I=(f)$, $f \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$?

Comment: @user237522 I doubt about it. $\mathbb C[x,y]$ is a UFD, so $f$ indeed factors uniquely into irreducibles $f = p_1^{n_1} \dots p_k^{n_k}$, but CRT is not applicable here. CRT relies on comaximality of ideals; in $\mathbb C[x]$, which is a PID, any irreducible generates a maximal ideal, and different maximal ideals are automatically comaximal, thus enabling the use of CRT. However, $\mathbb C[x,y]$ is not a PID, and different irreducibles in general don't generate comaximal ideals.

Comment: @lisyarus, thank you for the explanation. Perhaps if we further assume that $f \in \mathbb{C}[x]$, then CRT is still applicable (however, I prefer  considering $f \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]-\mathbb{C}[x]$).